# What is the meaning of "Jamás podréis ambicionar / Mentiras dijeron de mí" in the song from "No llores por mi Argentina"?

Tags: letras-de-canciones

Are there any Argentineans (or thoughts from anyone really) that might have some historical insight into the life and times of Eva Peron that would help with the translation of these lyrics from "No llores por mi Argentina" the Spanish translation of "Don't cry for me Argentina". The full lyrics can be found [here](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1077751).

I'm a bit stuck on exactly what is being said in these two lines:

> Jamás podréis ambicionar
>   Mentiras dijeron de mí

A literal translation doesnt seem to work ie:

> You can never aspire to
>   The lies they told about me

I am guessing the Lyricist's intent was more:

> You will never be able to understand the depth of the lies they told
>   about me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a bad transcription. The correct one is:

> Jamás poderes ambicioné
>
> Mentiras dijeron de mí

Which means

> I never had any ambition of power
>
> Lies were told about me